# Accessing and copying existing SQLite database

Tags: database, eclipse, sqlite

I've made a database named "CookbookDB" and put it into my assets folder.
Note: I changed the primary id field of my table to _id.

I'm having errors with this code. Any help?

Errors:

```
11-08 21:20:25.074: D/dalvikvm(624): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-08 21:20:25.534: E/Trace(624): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-08 21:20:25.734: E/SQLiteLog(624): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
11-08 21:20:25.734: E/SQLiteLog(624): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/data/data/com.cookbook.adiel/databases/CookbookDB) - 
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.cookbook.adiel/databases/CookbookDB'.
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.ExistingDBHandler.checkDataBase(ExistingDBHandler.java:61)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.ExistingDBHandler.createDataBase(ExistingDBHandler.java:42)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-08 21:20:25.755: E/SQLiteDatabase(624):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 21:20:25.755: D/AndroidRuntime(624): Shutting down VM
11-08 21:20:25.755: W/dalvikvm(624): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624): java.lang.Error: Database doesn't exist yet
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.ExistingDBHandler.checkDataBase(ExistingDBHandler.java:63)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.ExistingDBHandler.createDataBase(ExistingDBHandler.java:42)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.cookbook.adiel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-08 21:20:25.765: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The copying-methods part of my database handler class:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.cookbook.adiel/databases/";

     private static String DB_NAME = "CookbookDB";
 public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

         if(dbExist){
             //do nothing, database already exists
         }
         else{
             this.getDatabaseName();
             try{
                 copyDataBase();
             }catch(IOException e){
                 throw new Error("Error copying database");
             }
         }
     }
private boolean checkDataBase(){
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            }catch(SQLiteException e){
                throw new Error("Database doesn't exist yet");
            }

            if(checkDB != null){
                checkDB.close();
            }

            return checkDB!=null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
             InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
             String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; // Same as String myPath in checkDataBase()

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
             OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

             //transfer bytes from myInput to myOutput
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int length;
             while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                 myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
             }

             //Close the streams

             myOutput.flush();
             myOutput.close();
             myInput.close();

        }
```

On launcher:

```
ExistingDBHandler dbHandler = new ExistingDBHandler(this);
        try {
            dbHandler.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i =1; i<stories.length + 1;i++){
            stories[i-1] = dbHandler.getStory(i);
        }

        List<StoryType> storyList = dbHandler.getAllStories();
        for(int i = 0; i<stories.length; i++){
            Log.d("Checking if db is working", "Story " + i);
        }
```

Any help would be SO much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728